# var with fixed value that doesnt change with slicer dax

Tags: dax, var, fixed

I have a date table which I use as a slicer. I want date1 to get the minimum date from that range. I then use that date to calculate the number of new user from `KPI_summary` table andIi want this to be a fixed unchanging value which is returned as `newUsers`.

However when I plot this with dates the values change. am I missing something? pls see codes below

NewUsers =
var date1 = MIN('Date Table'[Date])  -- get the first date from the slicer
var newUsers = calculate(sum(KPI_SUMMARY[NEW_USERS]), KPI_SUMMARY[JOIN_DATE] = date1) --get the new users from the first date
return
newUsers -- I want to always return the newUsers from the first date of the slicer. it shouldnt change

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NewUsers =
-- get the first date from the slicer
var _date1 =
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('Date Table'[Date]),
        ALLSELECTED('Date Table')
    )
var _newUsers =
    calculate(
        sum(KPI_SUMMARY[NEW_USERS]),
        KPI_SUMMARY[JOIN_DATE] = _date1
    ) --get the new users from the first date
return
_newUsers -- i want to always return the newUsers from the first date of the slicer. it shouldnt change
```

I used **ALLSELECTED()** function inside **CALCULATE()** function to change *_date1* variable calculation context.
Also, as you can see, I would advice you to name your variables with "_" prefix. It's much easier to recognize them then.